# JAX-WS web service provider: omitting "complete" JAX-B bindings?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

We've got a WSDL refering to a complex XML schema. Instead of creating a complete JAX-B binding, we would like to obtain "unbinded" XML like a DOMSource or SOAPElement etc.

In the old days, we manually changed the schema and exchanged the specific message types for `xs:any`. But we feel quite bad about it.

In general, we could use plain web service annotations:

```
@WebServiceProvider(serviceName = "AbcWebService", portName = "AbcWebServicePort", targetNamespace = "urn:bla.bla", wsdlLocation = "AbcService.wsdl")
@ServiceMode(Mode.MESSAGE)
public class AbcWebService implements Provider<SOAPMessage> {
 @Override
 public SOAPMessage invoke(SOAPMessage request) { /* ... */ }
}
```

But this would serve all operations with one Java method and we would have to dispatch all ws operations on our own.

Instead we would like to have wsimport generate a Java method for each operation but still use some XML representation (DOMSource, SOAPElement etc.) instead JAX-B binding classes.

Any idea how we can achieve this?

Comment: You have access to that level of the message from a handler. Why not use that?

Comment: @kolossus But using a handler would not prevent the jaxb binding of the message, right? Doing this would then result in redundant objects one representing the 'plain' message from the handler and one object tree created be the JAXB Unmarshaller. In this case I would prefer to marshall the jaxb generated method parameters back into some xml stream.

Comment: Perhaps there needs to be some clarity of purpose here @0x0me, as I'm getting the feeling that this is an XY problem. If the purpose is to have a generic message, that can then be unmarshalled into any concrete type dynamically, JAXB provides the `@XmlAnyElement` and the `@XmlAdapter` for such usecases. OP appears to be looking for a solution that exposes the webservice operation as accepting a raw `SOAPMessage` which I doubt will look OK in a WSDL

Comment: Another available, but poorly documented feature is providing a custom JAXB context to the JAX-WS runtime